# Brothers and sisters I have none, Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> Brothers and sisters I have none,
>
> But evil cousins I have one.
>
> That doesn’t matter at all to me,
>
> For I have friends who help me defeat,
>
> The Evil one whom I cannot say.
>
> His name, or else others will be afraid.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> Harry Potter?

Brothers and sisters I have none,
But evil cousins I have one.

> He has no brothers or sisters, but has a cousin who is rude towards him, Dudley.

That doesn’t matter at all to me,
For I have friends who help me defeat
The Evil one whom I cannot say
His name, or else others will be afraid.

> The evil one, Voldemort, (He Who Must Not Be Named), is defeated by Harry Potter with assistance from his friends along the way.

Answer (score 2):

How easy is this...

The answer is most obviously

> Harry Potter.

And that's because..

> Harry, surely dosen't have any siblings but, yes he does have his muggle cousin Dudley, he has his dear friends, Ron, Hermione, Neville, and so many. And together they must defeat the one who must not be named.

Comment: This answer has already been submitted by Apollo